# Is there a difference when you create a private func vs creating a func in a private extension?

Tags: swift

Can I create private functions by putting my functions inside of a private extension of the class instead of creating new private functions by constantly calling `private func functionName(){}`?

Doing this:

```swift
private extension mClass {
    func mFuncOne(){}
    func mFuncTwo(){}
    func mFuncThree(){}
    func mFuncFour(){}
    func mFuncFive(){}
}
```

instead of:

```swift
class mClass {
    private func mFuncOne(){}
    private func mFuncTwo(){}
    private func mFuncThree(){}
    private func mFuncFour(){}
    private func mFuncFive(){}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, the difference is that the `private` `extension` makes the methods `fileprivate`, not `private`.

But the real question is why would one use a `private` `extension` rather than just declaring the individual methods as `private`?

We do this because:

- extensions facilitate the organization of our code, separating methods into logical groupings (e.g., it avoids intermingling private implementation details with public interface);
- the use of extensions affords code collapse of entire groups of methods within the Xcode IDE; and
- the marking of the whole extension as `private` avoids the syntactic noise of repeating `private` keyword for each method.

So, `private` methods and methods inside a `private` `extension` are not technically the same thing, but the difference is subtle and the `private` `extension` pattern is, nonetheless, extremely convenient. It concisely designates that none of the methods contained within are used outside of the current file.

Comment: People have been going on about the lack of `protected`-esque modifiers since 2014, so saying it's immaterial is going too far. `private` members are more accurate to intent than private extensions when the members will only be used by a single type within a file. `fileprotected` would be a more accurate description of how it operates.

Comment: We operate under the limitations of the access control that Swift provides. And given those constraints, I still contend that the utility of the private extension pattern outweighs those other concerns. But your point is taken.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this. It's just that the extension and the original declaration has to be in the same file. According to the [Swift Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html#ID25):

> Extensions that are in the same file as the class, structure, or enumeration that they extend behave as if the code in the extension had been written as part of the original type’s declaration. As a result, you can:
>
> - ...
> - Declare a private member in an extension, and access that member from the original declaration in the same file.